# Wordpress login issue after migrating the wordpress and database

Tags: wordpress

[See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jphNe.png)
I have migrated the database and wordpress folder on my localhost,I have made also made changes in wp-config file and wp-options table "siteurl" and "home" in database.
But When I try for login in mysite it redirects to wp-admin/installer.php page every time showing `"You appear to have already installed WordPress. To reinstall please clear your old database tables first."`It is not showing the admin dashboard.I have also disabled the plugin and used the default theme but still it showing error. So How can I access Dashboard?

I am new to wordpress please help me.

Comment: If your `siteurl` and `home` options are configured correctly, it's stange that you get redirected.

Comment: I have made the siteurl and home options correctly but i cannot redirect to admin dashboard

Answer (score 0):

I have a plan b. You can install [this plugin](https://www.akeebabackup.com/) on your localhost site. Make a backup. Then on your remote server you can use the `kickstart.php` to reinstall your site. It's a clean install with a `GUI` to modify the parameters. Here is a [video tutorial](https://www.akeebabackup.com/videos/1215-akeeba-backup-wordpress/1651-abtw05-restoring-site-new-server.html).

Maybe it's a solution for you.

Comment: I think so there is issue in database because on changing database name in wp-config to other already installed wordpress database it is redirecting to admin dashboard.

Comment: It's hard to confirm something that I can't see

Comment: IDK why, if you verified the parameters, but with my answer you need to restart but after that it will work.